# Why is gdebugger updating multiple textures in the texture viewer when rendering to an FBO?

Tags: opengl

I've got a really odd and frustrating problem happening in gDebugger at the moment, and I'm hoping someone can see what I'm doing wrong.

So as a bit of background info, in my code I have a stack of FBOs in order to accomplish the following type of scenario:

-I bind an FBO to render some stuff to the texture for the purpose of running a post-process shader on it at some point down the line

-Before finishing up with that FBO, I push another FBO onto the stack and bind that one, so that I can render some stuff to that texture, run a post-process shader on it, and then render the contents of that FBO's texture onto the original FBO

Although functionally this works just fine, debugging this in gDebugger has proven to be a nightmare since for some reason gDebugger shows multiple textures being updated whenever I render anything to an FBO.

I've attached some images to explain:

In this first one here, Tex 1 is a depth/stencil texture that I'm using for all FBOs (though, as a side note, I tested this same problem when not attaching a depth/stencil texture to the FBOs and it still happens, so I don't think that's a factor). Tex 2 is the texture attached to FBO 1, and Tex 3 is the texture attached to FBO 2. At this point in time, FBO 1 is bound. Despite that, it's updating texture 3 (FBO 2) whenever anything is rendered.

[image: Before rendering next texture]

As you can see in this image (the result of a single draw), FBO 1 has been updated (as expected) but so has FBO 2. 
[image: After rendering next texture]

Now even this isn't so bad - after all, I'm not using FBO 2 at this point, who cares if gDebugger updates the texture? Well the real problem is that if I bind FBO 2 and clear its color buffer, gDebugger clears FBO 1 (Texture 2) as well! And then if I render to FBO 2, FBO 1 is rendered to as well!

Now as I mentioned above, despite this weird behaviour, it actually all does functionality work as expected. That is, in the case where clearing FBO 2 shows that FBO 1 is cleared as well, it doesn't actually get cleared. But trying to debug a problem is almost impossible when the image information in the various FBOs doesn't seem to be accurate!

So, am I doing something wrong? Or is there a way to resolve this in gDebugger?

Thanks in advance!

Ryan